# Not able to reinstall apps from windows phone website?

Tags: 8.0, lumia

I got my Lumia 720 replaced from Nokia. But, on restore of the app list, it did not restore any of my previously installed apps.

So, I was trying to install each of these again from https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/my/purchase-history and https://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/my/purchase-history. But, on each and every app I am trying to reinstall from the list is giving the following error:

```
We can't send apps to your phone right now. Please try again later.
```

I have push notification settings kept on, which is required for this to work out.

Any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: On WindowsPhone.com, have you gone to the My Phone section and made sure the new phone is there and the old one has been removed?

Comment: In My Phone section, it is showing just Lumia 720. I couldn't find any way to identify whether my old Lumia 720 or the new Lumia 720. So, not sure whether it is showing new one or old one. And I did not find any option to remove old or add new phone option there.

Comment: In addition to that, I found Remove option in Account Settings page. But, if I need to add this again, I need to reset my phone. But, since after this post on restore of a bit old backup file on phone reset, I got all my apps back. So I don't want to reset my phone again since that'll cost me around a GB of data. But, anyway I hope this removal and addition back may help though I didn't try it myself.

Comment: How about My Account, then click on Update beside the image of the phone?

Comment: That again allows me to update my country and phone number. But, not anything related to new phone. I think the option of removing and adding the phone again may work. But, I don't want to try that now as it may clear out all my somehow restored app. I'll try this out if in any case I need to reset it in future. Probably you post that as an answer.

Comment: I am having the same problems with a brand-new Lumia 1020; never had a Windows Phone before. I tried installing Battery (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/battery/5dceaa39-8477-43f2-8499-91e816767517) this morning and got the same error.

Comment: i having the same problem with my account, its not logging in or even updating

Answer (score 2):

Although there may not be a definitive fix, there are a few things you can try:

1. Visit [WindowsPhone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/) and login.
2. Make sure your phone is listed (top right drop down menu). If you've recently received a replacement phone, make sure the old phone has been removed and the new one is selected.
3. If you have multiple phones, make sure the phone you want to install apps onto is selected (it appears you can only have 1 active phone at a time).
4. Now to go **Account Settings**, then click on **Update**. Make sure your phone number is correct and the option that allows *'Microsoft to send text messages to this number for Find My Phone and Windows Phone Store notifications'* is checked.

Some other observations:

- The phone may have to be unlocked for apps to install
- Make sure the phone has a proper data connection via a mobile network or Wifi connection
- Make sure the store region is correct when trying to download apps from WindowsPhone.com

I have followed the above steps with my Nokia Lumia 820 and remote app installation works. When the process starts, it does take a minute or two to finish to be patient :)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to enable sending apps to the phone in Settings -> "find my phone".

There is a checkbox to allow sending apps to the phone. Make sure it's checked.